# Xor algorithm with no special characters using VBA

Tags: vba, algorithm, excel, encryption, xor

For a project I am developing I need to use some kind of encryption algorithm to encrypt some sensitive data, where each user has a unique hex key.

Basically I have to encrypt a string and write it to a file to import to a Access database (we are not authorised to use other RDBMS as the company policies don't allow it).

So while researching what algorithms to use, I've came across this awesome sample of an XOR algorithm from [VBA Express](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=951), but there are some limitations with this particular algorithm (*please correct me if I'm wrong*) :

1. For certain combinations of string vs key, a overflow happens;
2. Excel uses a ["different" ASCII code table](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/strings-characters/ascii-characters.htm) which causes some entropy as well (can't use the first 32 codes because they refer to special characters);

I want to avoid special characters (line feeds, carriage returns) because I want to write to a file and if they exist I can't read the file as the splits will go bad.

With this being said, I can't maintain a 1 to 1 relationship of encoding and decoding.

1. So should I use another encryption system or are there changes should I do to fix this bad encryption?
2. Should I use another reading/writing file system other than line by line?

The code to generate the keys to test

```
    Private Sub getDictionaryValues()

        Dim atc As String
        Dim wsheet As Worksheet
        Dim wstmp As Worksheet
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim k As Long, j As Long
        Dim arrrr(1 To 223) As String
        Dim arc()

        On Error Resume Next

        j = 2
        Set wsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
        arc = Array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")

        For i = 33 To 255
            arrrr(i - 32) = Chr(i)
        Next i

        For k = LBound(arc) To UBound(arc)

            For i = LBound(arrrr) To UBound(arrrr)
                atc = XorC(arrrr(i), arc(k))
                wsheet.Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 1)) = arc(k)
                wsheet.Range(Cells(j, 2), Cells(j, 2)) = i + 32
                wsheet.Range(Cells(j, 3), Cells(j, 3)) = arrrr(i)
                wsheet.Range(Cells(j, 4), Cells(j, 4)) = Right(atc, Len(atc) - 3)
                wsheet.Cells(j, 5) = XorC(atc, arc(k))
                'wsheet.Cells(j, 6) = getUnicode(arrrr(i), arc(k))
                j = j + 1
            Next i
            atc = vbNullString
        Next k
    End Sub
```

My version of the Xor algorithm

```
    Function XorC(ByVal sData As String, ByVal sKey As String) As String

        Dim l As Long, i As Long, byIn() As Byte, byOut() As Byte, byKey() As Byte
        Dim bEncOrDec As Boolean
        Dim addVal

        If Len(sData) = 0 Or Len(sKey) = 0 Then XorC = "Invalid argument(s) used": Exit Function

        If Left$(sData, 3) = "xxx" Then
            bEncOrDec = False 'decryption
            sData = Mid$(sData, 4)
        Else
            bEncOrDec = True 'encryption
        End If

        byIn = sData
        byOut = sData
        byKey = sKey

        If bEncOrDec = True Then
            addVal = 32
        Else
            addVal = 1 * -32
        End If

        l = LBound(byKey)

        For i = LBound(byIn) To UBound(byIn) - 1 Step 2

            If (((byIn(i) + Not bEncOrDec) Xor byKey(l)) + addVal) > 255 Then
                byOut(i) = (((byIn(i) + Not bEncOrDec) Xor byKey(l)) + addVal) Mod 255 + addVal
            Else
                'If bEncOrDec Then
                If ((byIn(i) + Not bEncOrDec) Xor byKey(l)) - addVal < 32 Then byOut(i) = ((byIn(i) + Not bEncOrDec) Xor byKey(l)) + addVal
                If ((byIn(i) + Not bEncOrDec) Xor byKey(l)) - addVal > 255 Then byOut(i) = ((byIn(i) + Not bEncOrDec) Xor byKey(l)) - addVal
                If ((byIn(i) + Not bEncOrDec) Xor byKey(l)) > 32 And (byIn(i) + Not bEncOrDec) Xor byKey(l) < 256 Then byOut(i) = ((byIn(i) + Not bEncOrDec) Xor byKey(l))
            End If
            l = l + 2

            If l > UBound(byKey) Then l = LBound(byKey)

        Next i

        XorC = byOut

        If bEncOrDec Then XorC = "xxx" & XorC 'add "xxx" onto encrypted text
    End Function
```

Comment: This encryption algorithm is quite similar to the [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) and is trivially breakable.  Just use AES.

Comment: @TheGreatContini will there be a problem with special characters? Apologies for the ignorance :)

Comment: Not sure about special characters but found this VBA example of AES: https://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/906850-aes-encryption-algorithm-vba-vbscript

Comment: You need to encode your output to avoid these special characters.  Base64 of hex encoding will deal with the problem.

Comment: Text data types are for text. The result of encryption is not text or even necessarily compatible with text data types. If you want to convert the result of encryption to text use base 64 or similar.

Comment: If the data you are encrypting is not formatted to be recognizable or restrictive, an XOR **could** be 100% cryptographically secure and simple to implement. It would be what's referred to as a [One-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad). That being said data looks like "secret number: 012345" wouldn't work, but data that looks like "hcv03e59w6" could.